# Add extra space from span and li tag

Tags: html, css

I have the below screen where there is a space at the top of the vc-e-att-26 text. I tried all possible ways I could think of including negative margin. But it still doesn't work.

[image]

Mt html file is :

And my scss file is :

I need the vcs-e-att-26 txt to be in the same line as the bullet. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Did you try adding `!important` to css rule. It may be getting overwritten by another rule.

Comment: there is a big problemin your approch, let me give u a better solution , check answer in a while

Comment: In html structure `ul` should only get `li` as direct childre . Here you set a `p`. Why dont you set `p` tag into same `li` with `span` ?

Comment: Why put `li` with `width: 20px;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your `HTML and CSS` code, check the right code and solution [here](https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/vYKyZrv)

### DEMO

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
   }
span.right-text {
    float: right;
}
   h4 {
       margin:20px;
   }


hr {
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 57%;
}
ul li.my-class::before {
    background: red;
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
ul li.my-class.green-circle::before{
  background: green;
}
li.my-class {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.uptime-container{
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uptime-container">
  <h4>Uptime</h4>
  <ul *ngFor="let data of chartData">
    <li class="my-class red-circle">adadsadsad <span class="right-text">34324324234}</span></li>
    <hr>
    <li class="my-class green-circle">adadsadsad <span class="right-text">34324324234}</span></li>
    <hr>
    <li class="my-class green-circle">adadsadsad <span class="right-text">34324324234}</span></li>
    <hr>
    <li class="my-class green-circle">adadsadsad <span class="right-text">34324324234}</span></li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Will try it out and update the outcome.

Comment: For some reason, using the above code I am not able to render the red bullet point. The green bullet is getting rendered. but using the same code, the red bullet doesn't appear. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I think you miss `red-circle` class ... If you use class `red-circle` than a red bullet appear and when you use class `green-circle` than a green bullet will be appear

Answer (score 1):

There are some small mistakes:

1. nothing but LI can be the direct child of UL, you are having the P and other elements in UL, only LI can be directly present there and the rest will be the child of LI.
2. you have given the height and width directly to LI 10px, while all the data is present in you LI, that's why this mess was going on, if your data is dynamic and its can decrease and increase, its a very bad idea to give width to that element.
3. create your element with before or after or put an extra span for this round circle. don't style your complete LI like it.

Just a suggestion, Use flex instead of floats,

I have given the basic idea to you below use it,

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
   }

body {background-color: #ccc;}
   li span{
       color:black;
   }

   h4 {
       margin:20px;
   }

* {
padding: 0;margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
}
hr {
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 57%;
}


.uptime-container{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 80%;
}
.uptime-container ul li span {position: relative;  padding-left: 20px;}
.red-circle >span:after {
    content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

  .green-circle >span:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
.uptime-container ul li {
  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.uptime-container ul li:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="uptime-container">
  <h4>Uptime</h4>
  <ul *ngFor="let data of chartData">
    <li class="red-circle">
      <span>VCS-e-at-26</span>
      <p class="right-text">Down since lasrt 2 hours</p>
    </li>    
    <li class="green-circle">
      <span>VCS-e-at-26</span>
      <p class="right-text">10 minutes</p>
    </li>
    <li class="red-circle">
      <span>VCS-e-at-26</span>
      <p class="right-text">Down since lasrt 2 hours</p>
    </li>    
    <li class="green-circle">
      <span>VCS-e-at-26</span>
      <p class="right-text">10 minutes</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. I will give it a try and update in some time.